# Can't execute express application with visual studio code

Tags: express, visual-studio-code

I can't run a newly created express project with vscode. It simply fails with a message saying: "Cannot launch program 'xxxx'; setting the 'outDir' attribute might help."

My main executable file is in bin/www

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
```

Using vscode Version 1.12.1

Commit f6868fce3eeb16663840eb82123369dec6077a9b

Date 2017-05-04T21:40:39.245Z

Shell 1.6.6

Renderer 56.0.2924.87

Node 7.4.0

on Linux 4.8.0-51-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 25 16:32:21 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your `program` value should point to your express script. Like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'd try adding "trace": "all" to the launch config to see if you can get any helpful debug info from the console. Also read through this to see if it helps... https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7745

Comment: I have tried your advise, but the trace result doesn't give any information. Do you?
https://pastebin.com/hVCrexeM

Comment: Did you change the path to point to your entry script? It is still trying to launch a node script in this location "/home/oscar/projects/node/test/bin/www". I've only pointed this variable to a specific JS file before, not a directory.

Comment: As I said, /home/oscar/projects/node/test/bin/www is the file I wanna launch, and also the one I launch to start my Express application from command line, outside VSCode. This file is created by default by express generator http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html You can see its content here: https://pastebin.com/e1az7MtB

Comment: I created a new blank site with the express generator and used your exact  launch.json file with the same version of Code (1.12.1) - everything worked fine. (I am on Win10, though). Do you have the same problem when you create a new site with Express? Maybe it is some code you added that is causing it?

Comment: In Windows I followed the same approach without problems, it only happens on linux